# Pandas filter dataframe columns through substring match

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe, substring

I have a dataframe with multiple columns, eg:

```
     Name  Age   Fname
0    Alex   10   Alice
1     Bob   12     Bob
2  Clarke   13  clarke
```

My filter condition is to check if `Name` is (case-insensitive) substring of corresponding `Fname`.

If it was equality, something as simple as:

```
df[df["Name"].str.lower() == df["Fname"].str.lower()]
```

works. However, I want substring match, so instead of `==`, I thought `in` would work. But that gives error as it interprets one of the arguments as `pd.Series`. My 1st question is `Why this difference in interpretation?`

Another way I tried was using `.str.contains`:

```
df[df["Fname"].str.contains(df["Name"], case=False)]
```

which also interprets `df["Name"]` as `pd.Series`, and of course, works for some const string in the argument.

```
eg. this works:
df[df["Fname"].str.contains("a", case=False)]
```

I want to resolve this situation, so any help in that regard is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over index axis:

```
>>> df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Name'].lower() in x['Fname'].lower(), axis=1)]

     Name  Age   Fname
1     Bob   12     Bob
2  Clarke   13  clarke
```

`str.contains` takes a constant in first argument `pat` not a `Series`.

Comment: I just updated my answer before I saw yours. Our answers are now identical! :D

Comment: Isn't this too expensive?

Comment: Unfortunately, you have not really the choice here.

Comment: It depends on the size of your df. If you have 1000s of rows it might be...

Comment: I have around a million rows

Comment: Wow, then let me see if I can work something out.

Comment: Yes, can't really use this even if this works...its really bad for performance.

Comment: For 900K rows, it took 8.13s. It's not really so bad.

Comment: Since we used `apply` in a substring match situation, I inherently thought it must be bad. Let me test it for my actual use case then.

Comment: Since I am doing a lot of processing before this final filtering, 8-10s does not matter much for me. Hence accepting this answer.

Answer (score 2):

The .str accessor is extremely loopy and slow.  It is best most of the times using list comprehension.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import timeit
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas.testing as pt

def list_comprehension_lower(df):
    return df[[len(set(i)) == 1 for i in (zip([x.lower() for x in df['Name']],[y.lower() for y in df['Fname']]))]]

def apply_axis_1_lower(df):
    return df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Name'].lower() in x['Fname'].lower(), axis=1)]

def dot_string_lower(df):
    return df[df["Name"].str.lower() == df["Fname"].str.lower()]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[1, 5, 10, 30, 50, 100, 300, 500, 700, 1000, 10000],
    columns='list_comprehension_lower apply_axis_1_lower dot_string_lower'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

for i in res.index:
    d = pd.concat([df]*i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = '{}(d)'.format(j)
        setp = 'from __main__ import d, {}'.format(j)
        res.at[i, j] = timeit.timeit(stmt, setp, number=100)

res.groupby(res.columns.str[4:-1], axis=1).plot(loglog=True, ax=ax);
```

Output:

[image]

Now, back you your original question, You can use list_comprehension with `zip` and `in`:

```
df.loc[2, 'Fname'] += ' Adams'

df[[x in y for x, y in zip([x.lower() for x in df['Name']],[y.lower() for y in df['Fname']])]]
```

Output:

```
     Name  Age         Fname
1     Bob   12           Bob
2  Clarke   13  clarke Adams
```

Comment: Doesn't this graph show that it is better to use `.str.lower()`? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you are correct beyond a certain number of rows in this case .str lower out performs list comprehension.

Comment: that list comprehension is a double for loop, so the chart makes sense that at some point, Pandas str function will outperform it

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.apply()` with `axis=1` to call a function for each row:

```py
subset = df[df.apply(lambda x: x['Name'].lower() in x['Fname'].lower(), axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
>>> subset
     Name  Age   Fname
1     Bob   12     Bob
2  Clarke   13  clarke
```

Comment: My bad...there was a mistake in that particular line of code that I mentioned (edited). But please read through the whole question. This is not what I want. My requirement is "substring match"

Comment: @vish4071 check again; I updated the answer :)

Comment: Isn't this too expensive, esp for big dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Does this other option via a list comprehension work for you:

```py
df.loc[[left.lower() in right.lower() 
        for left, right 
        in zip(df.Name, df.Fname)]
       ]

     Name  Age   Fname
1     Bob   12     Bob
2  Clarke   13  clarke
```